# Error with pdfTeX after updating to Mac OS Catalina

Tags: errors, mac, mactex

I am getting the following error now when I compile with TeXShop.

```
"This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Oct11.tex/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex: getcwd: Operation not permitted"
```

Any ideas how to fix it?  It was working fine before updating to Catalina.

Comment: This has nothing to do with TeXShop. Your version of MacTeX is positively ancient (TL 2015). Please do yourself a favour and update to the latest version of MacTeX, which should work fine with Catalina.

Comment: Possible solution without upgrading (which you should do of course): modify the privileges of `pdflatex` as in http://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/.

Comment: @Mico I think you mean TL 2015? But TL 2015 contained 64bit binaries anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I figured out that when I updated to Catalina, the new OS restricted the permissions of TeXShop since it's a downloaded software.  I adjusted the permissions in the OS and it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

It is probably a matter of application file system permission for TexShop in Catalina. : Open General Settings -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy, select Full Disk Access in the left pane, then click + and add TexShop. I 
had the same with Emacs and Auctex and solved it with information provided [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53026/how-to-restore-file-system-access-in-macos-catalina) :

Comment: Just follow the instructions on OS settings and + add TexShop. The write enabled 18 will go away

Comment: For me this happened when trying to use locally Overleaf project added in my Dropbox directory. Just followed the answer and works ok since then. Thanks!