# Problems with TexShop after installing update

Tags: pdftex

I am running TexShop on a 2 year old Mac, running Catalina. I haven't worked on a file in a while, but I did update `TexShop`,
and now I am having problems.

One problem is, if I try to typeset a `LaTeX` file, I get an error like:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
> restricted \write18 enabled.
> entering extended mode
> (./notes2.ltx/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex: getcwd: Operation not permitted

If I move the file to my main Desktop folder, it will typeset correctly. If I try to typeset a `LaTeX` file in a different folder, that already has the .aux, .log, and .pdf files, I get an error of the form:

> ./Sym4notes.tex:0: I can't write on file `Sym4notes.log'. (Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit; default file extension is` .log')Please type another transcript file name:

So, to typeset correctly, I need to move or create a new `LaTeX` file in my main Desktop folder only.

I originally upgraded to version 4.72.

I then uninstalled `Texshop`, and uninstalled the Tex folder that is created from `MacTex`. I downloaded and installed `MacTex`, and this came with `TexShop` version 4.70.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! This may be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511617/error-with-pdftex-after-updating-to-mac-os-catalina

Comment: Does it really say `./notes2.ltx/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex`? It looks like you are not using the standard data structures for finding the binaries. In `TeXShop->Preferences` got to the `Engine` tab and make sure that the `Path settings` for `(pdf)TeX` is set to `/Library/TeX/texbin`.

Comment: Yes, it really does say that.  notes2 was the name of the latex file.

Comment: /Library/TeX/texbin  is the path in my settings for (pdf)Tex

Comment: I uninstalled version 4.70 of TeXShop, and then installed version 4.44.  This seems to have fixed the problem completely.  I don't know what was causing the problem for versions 4.70 and 4.72.  I can still work with 4.44, but would like to use the latest version.  Herb... thanks for responding, but I don't think that was the cause.

Comment: Actually, the first comment here, from LaTeXereXeTaL might be relevant.  I got this Mac new, running Catalina.  I upgraded to BigSur, but my logic card broke, and I had to send it in to Apple, where it was wiped clean, and they reinstalled Catalina.  I'm not sure if I worked on latex files before I updated TeXShop.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem, using IoS Big Sur and TexShop 4.70.

Answer (score 0):

My brand new MacBook Air (M2,2022) Version 12.5.1 with Apple M2 chip had the same problem. So I did move the file to the desktop as you said, and asked it to typeset. It asked me for permission to access the desktop folder and I hit yes, and the problem disappeared. It now typesets fine even with files anywhere else on my computer. Mystery. But happy it got resolved. So perhaps you need to somehow give TexShop access to the folder where you have your file. Anne Dow

Comment: I spoke too soon. It is now not working again for files outside the desktop. Don't know why it worked for a while. Anne Dow